# How to get HttpRequestMessage with PushStreamContent in .net core backend

Tags: c#, http, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement audio streaming from my Xamarin.Forms app to my backend (.net core 2.2).
Then my backend will call the Azure cognitive API to transcribe the voice in the audio and return back a string with the transcribed text.

The transcription has to be done and shown in a text box component while the user is speaking (not when he finishes speaking).

To record the audio and put it in a stream I am using the Plugin.AudioRecorder from Nate Rickard (https://github.com/NateRickard/Plugin.AudioRecorder) and it works well.
Basicly, it fills a stream with the audio while the user is speaking and saves it to a file.

Nate Rickard also has another plugin using the Azure cognitive service SpeechToText (https://github.com/NateRickard/Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech).
This one uses the Plugin.AudioRecorder to capture the voice and then an HttpClient to request the transcription to Azure, getting the text as response.
This solution does all the work in the Xamarin.Forms app and I would like the following:

- 1. Send the request stream to my backend instead of directly send it to Azure.
- 2. From my backend send the request to Azure.
- 3. Obtain the Azure response and send it back to my Xamarin.Forms app.

The 2nd and 3rd steps are identical as implemented in the Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech plugin. 
I am stuck in the first step when I have to handle the http request in my backend. 
Sending a HttpRequestMessage with a PushStreamContent in it as implemented in Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech plugin,
I have changed the URL to send it to my backend instead of send it to azure.

**When I run the app I get a 415 status code (Unsuported Media Type error).**

Here is the sample code of how the PushStreamContent is built (code from Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech plugin):

```
        HttpContent PopulateRequestContent (Stream audioStream, int? channelCount = null, int? sampleRate = null, int? bitsPerSample = null, Task recordingTask = null, int streamReadDelay = 30)
        {
            const int audioDataWaitInterval = 100; //ms
            const int maxReadRetries = 10; //times

            return new PushStreamContent (async (outputStream, httpContext, transportContext) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    byte [] buffer = null;
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    int readRetryCount = 0;

                    if (audioStream.CanRead)
                    {
                        var totalWait = 0;

                        //wait up to (audioDataWaitInterval * maxReadRetries) for some data to populate
                        while (audioStream.Length < ChunkSize && totalWait < audioDataWaitInterval * maxReadRetries)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine ("No audio data detected, waiting 100 MS");
                            await Task.Delay (audioDataWaitInterval);
                            totalWait += audioDataWaitInterval;
                        }

                        if (channelCount.HasValue && sampleRate.HasValue && bitsPerSample.HasValue)
                        {
                            //write a wav/riff header to the stream
                            outputStream.WriteWaveHeader (channelCount.Value, sampleRate.Value, bitsPerSample.Value);
                        }

                        //read 1024 (BufferSize) (max) raw bytes from the input audio stream
                        buffer = new byte [checked((uint) Math.Min (ChunkSize, (int) audioStream.Length))];

                        //probably a better way to do this... but if the caller has passed a Task in for us to determine the end of recording, we'll use that to see if it's ongoing
                        //  Otherwise, we'll always assume that the Stream is being populated and we'll fall back to using delays to attempt to wait for the end of stream
                        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool> ();
                        var waitTask = recordingTask ?? tcs.Task;

                        // loop while the stream is being populated... attempt to read <buffer.Length> bytes per loop, and see if we should keep checking, either via Task or read retries (when 0 bytes read)
                        while (audioStream.CanRead &&
                              ((bytesRead = await audioStream.ReadAsync (buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0 || !waitTask.Wait (streamReadDelay)))
                        {
                            if (bytesRead > 0)
                            {
                                readRetryCount = -1;

                                //write the bytes to the output stream
                                await outputStream.WriteAsync (buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            }

                            readRetryCount++;

                            //again, only using read retry timeouts if we don't have a Task
                            if (recordingTask == null && readRetryCount >= maxReadRetries)
                            {
                                tcs.SetResult (true);
                            }
                        }

                        await outputStream.FlushAsync ();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine (ex);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    //must close/dispose output stream to notify that content is done
                    outputStream.Close ();
                }
            }, new MediaTypeHeaderValue (Constants.MimeTypes.WavAudio));
        }
```

For test purposes I am using an overloaded method to build the PushContentStream:
HttpContent PopulateRequestContent (string audioFilePath){...} but, as in the plugin, the above one will be used.

Here is the request sent to my backend (code from Xamarin.Cognitive.Speech plugin MODIFIED to set my backend URL. I do not use the method parameters to build the request):

```
        async Task<string> SendRequest (Func<HttpRequestMessage> requestFactory, Func<HttpContent> contentFactory)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://localhost:5000/api/test/v1/speechtotext");

                httpRequest.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = true;
                httpRequest.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd(Constants.MimeTypes.Json);
                httpRequest.Headers.Accept.ParseAdd(Constants.MimeTypes.Xml);
                httpRequest.Version = HttpVersion.Version11;
                httpRequest.Content = PopulateRequestContent("/storage/emulated/0/Download/audioFile.wav");

                var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (response != null)
                {
                    // Do stuff
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine ("Error in sendRequest: {0}", ex);
                throw;
            }

            throw new Exception ("SendRequest: Unable to send successful request - unknown error or null response received");
        }
```

Here is my desired backend endpoint in my Controller class:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Receives stream content from request and calls service to send Azure SpeechToText request.
        /// </summary>
        /// <response code="200"> Ok. Returns transcribed text.</response>
        /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error. The search process ended with error.</response>       
        [HttpPost]
        [ProducesResponseType(200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(500)]
        [Route("/api/test/v1/speechtotext")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SpeechToText(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage)
        {
            // TODO: Get request, change URL to azure one and send it (have to see if so easy is possible).
            // OR
            // TODO: Get request, get PushStreamContent from it, build a new request, set the PushStreamContent as HttpContent and send it to azure


            // TODO: Receive azure response and send it back to Xamarin.Forms app.
        }
```

To be more precise, I only would like to know how to receive the HttpRequestMessage and get the PushStreamContent from it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello,

I've built a Node.js project using HTTP Push Streams and Server-Sent Events (SSE). It includes a server that sends random messages, a client script, and a simple HTML/CSS interface to display messages. Check it out here: https://github.com/emilianoeloi/EventSource. Your feedback or contributions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code get the file in the request

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var postedFile =httpRequest.Files[0];
```